# What to eat when you are a skinny fat?

Tags: nutrition, weight, body-fat, hips

I am 29 years old, I used to be fat, I was weighed more than 95 kg (I am 183 cm), And one day I decided to lose weight. I started to reduce food portions, no soda, no sugar on coffee and I lost 28 kg in 18 months, so I was 67kg (now I am 73 kg).

I do not do sport (just walking).

But something is still surprising me : I have super skin legs and shoulders and arms, but still have fat hips (not belly), it looks like my body is on a form of "A".

What can I do to lose those hips ? If I continue to reduce food, I think I'll be bonesy (especially on my face).

I am really lost and frustrated ! Is musculation and more food could be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

More physical activity would very probably be a good idea.
Body fat distribution has [genetic determinants](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28544651), and you cannot really target a body area for fat reduction. Conversely, exercising can have an impact on muscles and general fitness, in addition to [improving your mood](https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/pa-health/index.htm) and maybe helping you be more satisfied with your body. 
It does not have to be musculation: you may try swimming, running, body-weight training, yoga or any individual or team sport.